# Philodendron leaves losing colour and falling off

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, philodendron

My philodendron recently started losing a lot of leaves - to the point that some stems are now almost completely empty. The leaves first start getting pale, then yellowish, then very brittle with a bit of a harsh texture and eventually they fall off when even slightly touched.

What could be the reason?

I inspected the roots (the plant is in a transparent inner pot) and they seem fine. Also the plant is still producing new leaves at the end of the stems. Could it be caused by too little light?

[image: Philodendron]
[image: Philodendron]